# Can't find summernote.js in resources

Tags: javascript, summernote

[image]

[image]

[image]

my project can't fint summernote.js and css

'mybatis' is worked well using mapping.xml in resources/mappers

how can i solve it?

Comment: remove the `/` before  `/resources` and try it.if is not working show the `index` page url path

Comment: Did you mean like this? 'http://localhost:8081/imageBoard/board/write' I really appreciate your comment http://localhost:8081/imageBoard/board/write;jsessionid=31D1E53A3C2CA98C6B7269F0586BBB9D